# Install libnotify development package

Tags: elementary-os, libnotify

I want to build an elementary os bluetooth [github](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth) project on elementary os.  When I run

`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..`

it starts and checks some things.  Then error: `No package 'libnotify' found`.  This appears to be some kind of developer package.

How do I install this for elementary os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On elementary OS and other Debian-based distributions such as Ubuntu and Linux Mint, the package is `libnotify-dev`. Generally, to compile a program that uses the XXX library, you need the package called `libXXX-dev`.

You could start a terminal, log in as root (or, in case there is no root account, use `sudo -s`), and run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libnotify-dev
```

But there are other ways to install a package, as well.

Comment: for elementary os, sudo works fine